# IIS Redirecting by domain in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: https, iis-8, asp.net-mvc

I've created an app that is like a mini-shop, but now I have two problems with my clients:

Some of them want it to be their domain, instead of mine, say:  http://myshop.com/?shop=a197dc43fd89e should be: http://store.theirdomain.com

I can check their url on my system and autoassign a value to the shop var if they use CNAME or A record, but the problem comes when http changes to https.

Do I need to have a certificate in my server for each domain? If so, how can I make that process automatic so they can upload that certificate trough my webapp?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple approaches you can take.

one is to have semi-custom domains and a wildcard certificate. ie 
allow coolstuff.myshop.com, othercoolstuff.myshop.com etc and have a wildcard cert for *.myshop.com which will match all of these. they don't get a fully custom domain but perhaps enough of a unique domain to keep them happy.

you could have a single certificate with multiple SANs (subject alternative names). this is one certificate with multiple names, so it could be both store.theirdomain.com and myshop.com and somethingelse.com. each SAN normally costs as much as a certificate so the cost of a 3 SAN cert is the same as buying 3 certs. depending on how many customers you have who want custom domains this may or may not be a workable solution for you.

if neither of the above approaches work you're stuck with getting a certificate per custom domain. you'll have to write some custom code to allow these to be uploaded and properly associated with their sites. not worth it unless you have a large number of customers.